# update activity imageview from fragment webview javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, webview

There's a activity extends RoboFragmentActivity,it's main UI is a ViewPager to contain 3 fragments,xml below:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/goods_details_vp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:flipInterval="30"
                android:persistentDrawingCache="animation" />
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#cc000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/collection_view_lay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collection_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_goods_detials_collct_common" />
        </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

each fragment has a WebView,xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/goods_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</WebView>
```

The WebView in the 1st fragment will call a method like this:

```
class InJavaScript {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void runOnAndroidJavaScript(String status) {
            collectionStatus.setCollectionStatus(status);
        }
    }
```

the callback method in activity :

```
    @Override
    public void setCollectionStatus(String str) {
        // TODO 设置收藏图标
        if ("true".equals(str)) {
            collectionView
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_goods_detials_collct_pressed);
        } else {
            collectionView
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_goods_detials_collct_common);
        }
    }
```

Now , **the question is** ,if I let collectionView to setImageResource ,the fragments will all disappeared.The method is already ran,I can even get the str above like "true".if I change the code above like :

```
@Override
    public void setCollectionStatus(String str) {
        Log.e("tag", str);
    }
```

the log runs perfectly.I got confused with this problem,hope you can help me.Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,cannot update parent view from a child view,so we need to add a `runOnUiThread` in the callback method.Code below:

```
 @Override
        public void setCollectionStatus(final String str) {
            goodsDetailsActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if ("true".equals(str)) {
                        collectionView
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_goods_detials_collct_pressed);
                    } else {
                        collectionView
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_goods_detials_collct_common);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```